# Obtaining test results from another job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline A that looks something like this

- Run prebuild tests
- Build project
- Run post-build tests
- Run another pipeline B with parameters extracted from current build

I was wondering if there was a way to get test results from pipeline B and aggregate them with the tests results of pipeline A. 
Currently, I have to open the console output and open the Url to the external build.

If the above is not possible, is it possible to display this Url somewhere else than the console (e.g. as an artifact ).

Comment: You can write output to a file otherwise your results may be overridden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is "stash". Below is copied directly from https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/

> Synopsis
>   This is a simple demonstration of how to unstash to a different directory than the root directory, so that you can make sure not to overwrite directories or files, etc.

```
// First we'll generate a text file in a subdirectory on one node and stash it.
stage "first step on first node"

// Run on a node with the "first-node" label.
node('first-node') {
    // Make the output directory.
    sh "mkdir -p output"

    // Write a text file there.
    writeFile file: "output/somefile", text: "Hey look, some text."

    // Stash that directory and file.
    // Note that the includes could be "output/", "output/*" as below, or even
    // "output/**/*" - it all works out basically the same.
    stash name: "first-stash", includes: "output/*"
}

// Next, we'll make a new directory on a second node, and unstash the original
// into that new directory, rather than into the root of the build.
stage "second step on second node"

// Run on a node with the "second-node" label.
node('second-node') {
    // Run the unstash from within that directory!
    dir("first-stash") {
        unstash "first-stash"
    }

    // Look, no output directory under the root!
    // pwd() outputs the current directory Pipeline is running in.
    sh "ls -la ${pwd()}"

    // And look, output directory is there under first-stash!
    sh "ls -la ${pwd()}/first-stash"
}
```

Basically you can copy your artifacts, say .xml files that result from running unit tests, from the first job to the node running the second job. Then have the Unit test processor run on both the results from the first and the second job.